# I'm getting a wrong answer in CodeChef and I don't know why. What should be my approach to get it correct?This is an example

Tags: c

Here is the question : [Question](https://www.codechef.com/problems/HS08TEST)

[My solution](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/34661088)
is giving exactly required output but resulting some error(runtime error - NZEC)

I referred to a already submitted solution -> [correct solution](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/34659736)
This has the same logic i used

I tried solving few other problems,but all resulted in some issue similar to this.

Please let me know where the error is

Comment: Your question is probably related to CodeChef's grading infrastructure (see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nzec-error-python/ for NZEC error). Please bring it up with the website's administration.

Comment: You don't check if `scanf` read something useful (i.e. check its erturn value)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie that is one reason why those sites make a poor learning resource. The input  is *guaranteed* to be as described, so there is no need to check, and there is no alternative strategy if the unexpected value is returned: the code will just fail anyway.

Comment: @EeshKumar the way to approach this is to build some test cases yourself (to cover the full range of input specified), and thoroughly work out the code. Outside of the CodeChef environment, you can test and debug your work. You chose to tackle the problem, and equally it is up to you to solve the *challenge*. You especially should go over your code looking for array bounds abuse and uninitialsed variables which account for the runtime error.

Comment: Please post the question and a minimal example of your code here on this site, as text.

Comment: I think the addition of the `int` with the `float` can cause some issue (for example with `100 100.0`)

Comment: Please be clear too about the actual problem. Here you say it gives the required output, the wrong answer, and a runtime error.

Comment: It is beacuse the code has a `void` return type for `main()`, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have declared the return type of `main()` as `void`. Moreover, you have also tried to return an `int` 0 at the last line. I don't even blame you because a lot of resources still teach that the return type of `main()` is `void`.
Ancient compilers like the Turbo C compiler don't warn you about it because they were developed far before C was standardized. The C standard requires that you define your `main()` method as `int main() {.. }`. Change it to `int` and the error disappears.
The return value of `main()` decides if the code has run successfully. 0 means it was successful. If you return a non-zero exit code, it means the code was abnormally terminated.
`NZEC` means Non-Zero Exit Code. It probably is due to some garbage value as the return type is `void`.

Answer (score 0):

*Firstly*,

your program has errors in it. You have declared `void` as the return type of `main()` i.e, `void main()` yet you are returning integer value at the end.

*Secondly,*

**Do Not consider** the given test cases as the ‘sole’ test cases…”

most of the times it is advisable to have your own test case which is ‘manually’ worked out as a reference. depending on the complexity of the test cases you generate, less is the number you have to generate.

Also @Eesh Kumar you have made a logical error in the code. In the `if()` condition of your program (line 9) you have to make the change the codition as:

```
    if( (monwithdraw+0.5>bankbalance) /*rest of your code*/)
    printf("%.2lf",bankbalance);
```

This change is required as considering from the advice in first paragraph of my answer: *Do Not consider the given test cases as the ‘sole’ test cases…”*.
Try this case out, `monwithdraw=10  bankbalance=10.2`.
Consider the above sample input and how your previous code generates undesired and incorrect output (-0.30 which is wrong) accordingly.
I have made a few changes in your code and it works fine. You can check it out [here](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/34681229) . Hope it helps.